# Why this array prints only last value outside of the loop? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am having this strange problem. I have a loop where I am looping through an array and executing a query for each id I get in the loop:

```
$select_deleted_arr=[];

foreach ($selected_devices as $devs) {
    $select_deleted_devices->bind_param("i", $devs);
    $select_deleted_devices->execute();
    $select_deleted_devices_res = $select_deleted_devices->get_result();  
    $select_deleted_arr = $select_deleted_devices_res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
$select_deleted_devices->close();
print_r($select_deleted_arr);
```

which prints :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [serial_imei] => 573 [serial_no] => 88888893 [name] => test device [device_no] => 1233 [barcode] => 44556633 ) )
    return;
```

And when I print the array inside the loop:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [serial_imei] => 569 [serial_no] => 88888889 [name] => test device [device_no] => 1233 [barcode] => 44556633 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [serial_imei] => 573 [serial_no] => 88888893 [name] => test device [device_no] => 1233 [barcode] => 44556633 ) )
```

I have no idea why is it behaving like this because I am doing exactly the same thing multiple times in my project but it always works perfectly fine. Any idea?

Comment: use `$select_deleted_arr[] = $select_deleted_devices_res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: @RoyBogado thanks it worked, but can you explain why it doesn't work here but it works in my other cases?

Comment: Becouse you are overwriting in an normal variable and not in an array.

Comment: @RoyBogado but I am doing exactly the same in other cases and its working.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @RoyBogado in fact its nesting arrays multiple times: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [serial_imei] => 569 [serial_no] => 88888889 [name] => test device [device_no] => 1233 [barcode] => 44556633 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [serial_imei] => 573 [serial_no] => 88888893 [name] => test device [device_no] => 1233 [barcode] => 44556633 ) ) )`

Comment: @RoyBogado please check my comment above. I tried as you told me and it prints like that.